# React Props not displaying data on UI

Tags: reactjs

**I am learning React**

While working on Props, I have created a component and using that component in my index.jsx. But the values passed through props are not displayed on the UI.

**usingprops.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
class UsingProps extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>{this.props.headerProp}</p>
                <p>{this.props.contentProp}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UsingProps;
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import UsingProps from './Props/UsingProps.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <UsingProps />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const myElement = <App headerProp="Header from props!!!" contentProp="Content from props!!!" />;
ReactDOM.render(myElement, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the `headerProp` on the `App` component, not the `UsingProps` component, which is where you are trying to access it.  You need to revise it to this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <UsingProps headerProp="Header from props!!!" contentProp="Content from props!!!" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```